# selecting objects from a dictionary based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like:

```
dd = {"one":"red", "two":"red", "three":"blue", "four":"yellow", "five":"blue"}
```

I would like to create a simple line "if" to go through and select the objects that have a value, let's say "blue".

My attempt:

```
dd = {"one":"red", "two":"red", "three":"blue", "four":"yellow", "five":"blue"}
for number in dd:
     if 'blue' in dd.values():
          print("The number "+number+", likes color blue!")
     else:
          print("I'm a number that do not like color blue")



The number one, likes color blue!
The number three, likes color blue!
The number two, likes color blue!
The number five, likes color blue!
The number four, likes color blue!
>>>
```

It's not working.

I'm looking to select just the objects that have value "blue" and print the statement just for them.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Psidom has already provided a better answer, but this is the minimal change answer.

```
dd = {"one":"red", "two":"red", "three":"blue", "four":"yellow", "five":"blue"}

for number in dd:
     if 'blue' == dd[number]:
          print("The number "+number+", likes color blue!")
     else:
          print("I'm a number that do not like color blue")
```

In your code you check against the same thing in each iteration, so guess what! It's always the same result.

If you iterate over a `dict` in the `for x in y` method generally used for lists, then you get the `dict` keys as the iteration variable, so if you just use that as an index back into the `dict`, you get the value. It's not as efficient as `d.items()` though, as it requires calculating the hash for each item and possibly walking a list of items for which the hashes collide.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!

Comment: This worked very well and it was what I was looking for. I was missing the python syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through `items` and check the value along the way, if the value is `blue` print the key:

```
for k, v in dd.items():
    if v == "blue":
        print("The number " + k + ", likes color blue!")

# The number three, likes color blue!
# The number five, likes color blue!
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'items' method:

```
dd = {"one":"red", "two":"red", "three":"blue", "four":"yellow", "five":"blue"}
for number, color in dd.items():
    if color == 'blue':
        print("The number "+number+", likes color blue!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator:

```
dd = {
    "one": "red",
    "two": "red",
    "three": "blue",
    "four": "yellow",
    "five": "blue"
}

for number in (k for k, v in dd.items() if v == 'blue'):
    print("The number " + number + ", likes color blue!")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dd = {"one":"red", "two":"red", "three":"blue", "four":"yellow", "five":"blue"}

for number in dd: 
    if dd[number] == 'blue':
        print("The number "+number+", likes color blue!")
    else:
        print("I'm a number that do not like color blue")
```

**Output:**

```
I'm a number that do not like color blue
The number three, likes color blue!
The number five, likes color blue!
I'm a number that do not like color blue
I'm a number that do not like color blue
```

You're if statement was giving whole list rather than giving just a value every time... I just edited your if statement, the rest of code is same...